# How to print individual elements of an array as numbers or integers

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

I have array with elements for example

array = [1213141,1311414,131411511]

I don't know how to print in this format:

ids = 1213141,1311414,131411511

Any help?

Comment: with [`Array#join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) probably ...?

Comment: Please clarify what you are trying to do because `ids = 1213141,1311414,131411511` is most certainly not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

## Array.join(',')

```js
const array = [1234123, 1234123, 1234123];
array.join(',');
```

Answer (score 0):

try `[1,2,3].toString()`

for a more detailed answer you should tell us your intention.

Answer (score 0):

### Array.toString()

You can user **.toString()** function of javascript like below.

```
let array = [1213141,1311414,131411511];
array.toString();
```

Output will return in string like **"1213141,1311414,131411511"**

Comment: You want to print each elements of array in html right?

Comment: You need to improve your questions and also you can't store value like 1213141,1311414,131411511 this in any variable.